# Subclassed UItableViewCell selection

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have subclassed a UITableViewCell so that I can increase the scrolling performance which has worked out great for me so far.

In my subclass I have a method called seSelected that looks like this

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if (selected) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }else{
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to make it so that if I touch the same cell it deselects the cell and changes the color back to white? I have tried a few different if statments in setSelected but nothings working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and call here method which manage selected and unselected cell.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to set the tag on the cell and then use it to set the background color.

```
typedef enum {
    CellSelected = 0,
    CellDeselected
} CellSelection;
```

While creating the cell set the tag to "CellDeselected"

```
cell.tag  = CellDeselected;
```

And then when cell is tapped just check which color you want to set in the background.

```
switch (customCell.tag) {
    case CellSelected:
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        break;
    case CellDeselected:
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

customCell.tag = !customCell.tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    str = [YourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//str is a string variable
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *cellIndentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [reminder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if ([str isEqualToString:[reminder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

You can use for this for your custom cell.....

Answer (score 0):

use UITableViewCell method: `[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:myBgColorView];`.
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selectedBackgroundView).
Example:

```
UIView *myBgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
myBgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:myBgColorView];
```

Answer (score 0):

set cell style:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

and your code will work. But, you set color only selected cell.
If you need set color when cell is pressed, override this method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```